# Failed to turn Objects into Faults (Core Data )

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, fault

I am trying to turn objects into Faults with the following code, but failed.

**User.m**

```
@implementation User

...

-(void)memoryWarningHandle{
    if (![self.avatar isFault]) {
       [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self.avatar mergeChanges:NO];

        if ([self.avatar isFault]) {
           NSLog(@"isFault");
         // Never went into here
        }
    }
}
...
```

Here `User` is an Entity and `avatar` is an Attribute of `User`.

As said in the Apple Document:

> refreshObject:mergeChanges: Updates the persistent properties of a
>   managed object to use the latest values from the persistent store.
>
> - (void)refreshObject:(NSManagedObject *)object mergeChanges:(BOOL)flag Parameters object A managed object. flag A
>     Boolean value.
>
> If flag is NO, then object is turned into a fault and any pending
>   changes are lost. The object remains a fault until it is accessed
>   again, at which time its property values will be reloaded from the
>   store or last cached state.
>
> If flag is YES, then object’s property values are reloaded from the
>   values from the store or the last cached state then any changes that
>   were made (in the local context) are re-applied over those (now newly
>   updated) values. (If flag is YES the merge of the values into object
>   will always succeed—in this case there is therefore no such thing as a
>   “merge conflict” or a merge that is not possible.)

The `avatar` must be fault after `[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self.avatar mergeChanges:NO];` is called, but it is not. What's going on here? Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT 1**
I test the code as following:

```
-(void)memoryWarningHandle{
    self.avatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];
    NSLog(@"self.avatar :%@",self.avatar);
    NSLog(@"self.managedObjectContext :%@",self.managedObjectContext);
    if (![self.avatar isFault]) {
       [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self.avatar mergeChanges:NO];

       if ([self.avatar isFault]) {
          NSLog(@"isFault");
        // Never went into here
       }
    }
}
```

NSLog Results:

```
2013-05-23 11:58:30.072 myApp[10967:907] self.avatar :<UIImage: 0x1d5f6e20>
2013-05-23 11:58:30.947 myApp[10967:907] self.managedObjectContext :<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1e898c10>
```

Comment: could you log `self.managedObjectContext` and `self.avatar`? are they nil?

Comment: @DanShelly if (![self.avatar isFault]) here tells the self.avatar is not Fault, I will log them latter:)

Comment: That does not mean that it is not nil. try `[nil isFault]` you will get `NO`

Comment: @DanShelly I have update the post, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage` is not a subclass of `NSManagedObject` you cannot refresh is, nor does it respond to `isFault`.
In any case, you cannot fault a specific property on a `NSManagedObject`, you must fault the entire object.

try `[[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:self mergeChanges:NO]` to fault your entire object.

If you like to fault only the picture data, add a to-one relationship (say `imageContainer`) to an entity that hold the image data in a property (say `imageData`), and then refresh that relationship on the object like so:

```
[[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:self.imageContainer mergeChanges:NO]
```

You should have got an exception in your code like: `Unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

Comment: have you implemented message forwarding or `valueForUndefinedKey` somewhere?

Comment: Seems not. I mean there is no exception in [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self.avatar mergeChanges:NO];

Comment: You should get an exception for `[self.avatar isFault]`